# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un texto esté en la parte inferior de su caja?

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo los fundamentos de CSS, voy con la propiedad line-height y he aprendido que esa propiedad me da la altura de la caja del texto. Pero cuando sombreo (con el mouse) un texto, veo que ese texto se encuentra centrado en el eje Y.

[image: Aquí se muestra el texto centrado en el eje Y]

Y me estaba preguntando si existe una manera de que ese texto esté en la parte de abajo, es decir, en la parte que está en círculo rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que tiene que existir alguna propiedad, pero no sé cuál es.

Answer (score 4):

Primero tienes que saber que hay etiquetas que tiene propiedades de serie. En este caso la etiqueta **p** tiene un margen, tu estabas pendiente de **line-height** que es el espacio que tiene entre línea y línea cuando el texto llega hasta el final.

Para posicionar elementos yo siempre uso flexblox, en el ejemplo que te he puesto "activamos" flexbox con **display: flex;** y lo centramos horizontalmente con **justify-content: center;**

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Tu texto</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar que etiqueta estas usando para el texto.

Por lo general dependiendo de la etiqueta ella trae por defento un padding y un margin; que es lo que puede estar impidiendo que el texto quede en la parte inferior.

Quitado el padding y el margin se quitaria el impedimento paa posicionarse en la parte inferior prueba con por ej si la etiqueta es p:

```
p {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   }
```

Tambien tendrias que verificar que el contenedor no tenga un padding-bottom que impida que el texto quede en la parte inferior por ej:

```
div{
    padding-botton: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como siempre sin código no podemos ver como tienes la estructura de tus elementos, así edita tu pregunta y pon el código.

---

Pero quiero rescatar otra cosa del post.

> Estoy aprendiendo los fundamentos de CSS, voy con la propiedad line-height y **he aprendido que esa propiedad me da la altura de la caja del texto**.

Error, **line-height** lo que hace, así en palabras sencillas, es definir el **interlineado** de tu texto. Y cito [este interesante articulo](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/referencia-css2/line-height) y también el de [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

> La propiedad **line-height** establece la altura de cada línea que forma el contenido de texto de un elemento, **por lo que se emplea para controlar el interlineado del texto**. El uso de **line-height es imprescindible cuando se quiere facilitar la lectura de los contenidos de una página**.

Así que tu defines el **line-height** en altura o normal y siempre hara que haya un espacio entre cada línea de texto o incluso entre otros elementos. Sino quieres ese espacio puedes **no usar esa propiedad** y manejar los contenidos con padding, margin, o alineándolos en el bottom (abajo) del elemento y eso respondería la duda que planteas en el tema del post.

Ojo mi respuesta va enfocada a que **line-height** no da alturas de cajas de texto, sino que es un interlineado como lo harían en MS-Word o símiles. Para esos que de una van a comentar que no "resuelve" exactamente la duda que ha planteado el OP.